# Regular Expression to find "ABA", "AABBAA" or "AAABBBAAA" (until infinity)

Tags: python, regex

**How do I write a regular expression to find:**

- ABA
- AABBAA
- AAABBBAAA
- AAAABBBBAAAA
- AAAAABBBBBAAAAA

**Rules:**

- It always begins and ends with A
- It always has a B in the middle
- The first group of A's, the group of B's in the middle, and the second group of A's all must have the same amount of letters.
- Must be valid all the way to infinity

Comment: You can satisfy all your requirements but one with the regular expression `^(A+)(B+)\1$`.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWmWUP/2/). The exception is the need to confirm the sizes of the strings in the two capture groups are equal. For that I believe you will need a separate statement such as `$1.size == $2.size`, which will depend on the language you are using.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm using Python. What are those statements? I'm googling it, but haven't figured it out yet. Thanks.

Comment: You need to first see if the string matches the regex I gave (which I should have written `r'^(A+)(B+)\1$'`. If there's a match you then need to use Python code to test whether the length of the string in capture group 1 equals the length of the string in capture group 2. I believe you need to get a match object `m` and test whether the size of the string `m.group(0)` equals the size of the string `m.group(1)`. Is there a Pythonite in the audience?

Comment: The argument being made in the comments above is that a regular expression _isn't adequate_ on its own. Adding extra code to do a check after the regex is complete is not in any way providing a regex that meets all the stated requirements.

Comment: (This is probably appropriate; I don't believe a fully complete answer is *possible*; for true/standardized ERE or BRE regex forms, so someone needs to be very careful about how the word "regex" is interpreted if they want to state otherwise).

Comment: BTW, is this homework? Why would you choose a regex as the right tool for this job, and insist that only a regex-based answer is acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

**No possible regex language can describe this, because the language described isn't a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).**
Quoting from the Wikipedia link above:

> The collection of regular languages over an alphabet Σ is defined recursively as follows:
>
> - The empty language Ø, and the empty string language {ε} are regular languages.
> - For each a ∈ Σ (a belongs to Σ), the singleton language {a} is a regular language.
> - If A and B are regular languages, then A ∪ B (union), A • B (concatenation), and A* (Kleene star) are regular languages.
> - No other languages over Σ are regular.

No combination of fixed strings, union, concatenation, or Kleene-star operations (which are necessarily zero-or-more without further constraints) can describe the above, because there is no operator that allows length-matching assertions. (Similarly, "regex" languages that allow backreferences are not true regex languages either).

Thus, any "regex syntax" that can describe the above language is not truly a regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work for the scenario described above and also with the exception @Cary Swoveland is talking about.

**code**

```
import re
count = 0
string = "AABBAA"
for i in string:
    if i == string[0]:
        count +=1
    else:
        break
#count = 2
R = "^(A+)(B{" + str(count) + "})(\\1)$" #^(A+)(B{2})(\1)$
#print(R)
r = re.compile(R)
print(re.findall(r, string))
```

you will have to count the the number of occurrences of `A` in string as you want the pattern to match those strings which have equal number of `B`(s).

**output**

```
[('AA', 'BB', 'AA')]
```

when `string = "AAABBBBBBAAA"`

**output**  `[]`

Comment: You're constructing a new regex specific to each string. This is not _a_ regex that matches only strings in the form the OP describes.